# I get "There was a problem processing your request" when buying or accepting an offer on OpenSea

Tags: solidity, nft, testnets, polygon, opensea

I made my own collection of NFTs on OpenSea and I'm trying to buy or accept offers.
The network I'm using it Polygon (Mumbai).
The problem is, that there's no way, or at least I couldn't find a way, to debug the error. The console is empty, and there are no actual transactions happening on the network that I can debug.

Does anybody know what functions is OpenSea running in the background? Maybe I can go there step by step? Or is there a way to debug this message that I don't know about?

Comment: Did you try contacting OpenSea support? If you have a transaction hash we can take a look but we can't answer if it is something internal to OpenSea API.

Comment: Yes I tried to reach out on Discord and I opened a ticket. But discord is mostly spam or 30 consecutive questions with no answers. And a lot of users including me have opened tickets and never got a response.

I guess I'll try to work with their SDK and API